# how to fetch data from JSON into UIPickerView using swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to fetch data from JSON into UIPickerview but i don't the format for parsing that data and fetch it from picker.

[image]

I need to get name and code from parsed data in my pickerview when i tap the textfield
**Parsed code**

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://api.railwayapi.com/v2/name-to-code/name/\. (pickTxtField.text!)/apikey/fe22em16kb")! //change the url
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else { return
        }
        guard let data = data else { return
        }
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
             {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        var display = String(describing: json["stations"]!)
                        let realname = json["code"]
                        let departmentName = json["name"]
                        self.department.append(departmentName! as! String)
                        self.pickView.reloadAllComponents() // this is reference to your pickerView. Make it global and use it
                }
            }
        }catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription) }
    })
    task.resume()
```

Comment: post a code snippet to show how far you did that helps others to understand  and make them to help you easy

Comment: Please learn how to read and parse JSON. There are countless tutorials and [more than 400 related questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BSwift3%5D+parse+JSON)

Comment: Lear how to read and parse JSON as suggest by @vadian. Also, learn how to debug, because I doubt that `let realname = json["code"]`, nor `let departmentName = json["name"]`` returns the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data from api which will most probably be an array. Implement the datasource of UIPickerView, number of rows equal to the size of that array and show title for each row from the array at respective index.

Comment: *most probably* means you are guessing (by the way wrongly), but according to the JSON in the question you are supposed to **know** that the API returns a dictionary. Reading JSON is no rocket science, there are only two collection types.

Comment: You need to check the response in the json screenshot. Stations is an array type object and Jesme want to load that array to UIPickerView